# android parse google image

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to parse image from google with android 
it's work for me and for another friend of mine but it doesn't 
work for some one else

When i asked him for his error he said that the Element im object was empty 
and when i run my program it have 22 elements

```
private void setImageFromGoogle(final String name) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String url = "https://www.google.co.il/search?q=" + name + "&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpq_CYh4jRAhXXdFAKHSOBCe0Q_AUICCgB&biw=1680&bih=920";
                final Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Chrome").get();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build());
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(getImageBitmap(doc.select("[src]").get(1).attributes().get("src")));
                    }
                });
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        runToast(e.toString());
                    }
                });
                Log.e("error", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using an AsyncTask?

Comment: I'm used to work with thread,

Comment: Do you think that could be the problem?

Comment: I doubt it, but the use of `StrictMode` is concerning and should not be relied upon. Test your code in multiple emulators and other devices you have available.